# what happens when open beta test is closed again

Tags: android, google-play, beta-testing

if I run a open beta test for payable app in google play store, what happens if I close the beta test. Will the users still be able to use the app forever ?

Situation:
1. I open my App for open beta test
2. USER A finds the app in GooglePLay for betatesting (Thats I guess, not sure how it works really )
3. After while I close the betatest phase.
4. Will USER A still be able to use the app ?

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere in documentation they go back to the available public version and cant re-enroll as an open beta tester until the next public release is shipped live.

Answer (score -1):

If you close the open beta testing and move on to some other type of testing like closed beta testing or alpha testing, the user (if not mentioned as a tester in the closed beta testing or alpha testing) will be able to use your app but will not be able to make any purchases.

Hope this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: Not sure if I understood. I have a payable app. For an open beta test I have to set at least 1000 testers. If 1000 users are downloading my alpha version, which is the future production release, will all 1000 users becomse the "productive" version for free forever ?